# biber command not working in texmaker

Tags: biber

In spite of changing in the configuration from bibtex to biber and in the user command entering a command option of biber, biber does not work. the message I get is Could not start command "book":biber "book"

Comment: Show how you configured texmaker. Also did you try to run biber on the command line? Did it work?

Comment: Please refer to [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) for information on the proper setup. If you still have problems, please show us your exact configuration as well as pastes of the exact error messages. (If nothing works try to call Biber from the command line.)